# %AddJar for hellospark_2.10-1.0.jar giving Name: java.util.zip.ZipException Message: error in opening zip file

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud, jupyter-notebook

Using Bluemix (console.ng.bluemix.net) Spark notebook to run the above step. I am getting an exception error. This is my build (using standard procedure outlined with docs; used sbt). 
I tried bunch of others from publicly posted on github as well as jazz hub. All stop at this very first step, with an exception. 
I am unable to proceed further - this started at around this time yesterday (was not a problem previously). Thank you.

Comment: Can you specify the full command that you are trying:-
%Addjar -f <url>

Comment: It looks like hellospark_2.10-1.0.jar has been replaced with helloSpark-assembly-2.1.jar. See this commit log :https://github.com/ibm-cds-labs/spark.samples/commit/d575f507997c36664c272ac0c21aafcced1870df#diff-2a6d07eef8b10b84129b42424ed99327

Comment: Resolved. Need to use 'raw', instead of just URL link.Click on the jar file in Github, next page shows a button / link with text 'raw'. Used this raw, looking good now.