# %AddJar for hellospark_2.10-1.0.jar giving Name: java.util.zip.ZipException Message

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud, data-science-experience

I am trying to run AddJar in my new notebook in ibm bluemix.

```
%AddJar https://github.com/ibm-cds-labs/spark.samples/blob/master/dist/helloSpark-assembly-2.1.jar -f
```

However, I keep receiving this error -

```
Starting download from https://github.com/ibm-cds-labs/spark.samples/blob/master/dist/helloSpark-assembly-2.1.jar
Finished download of helloSpark-assembly-2.1.jar
Out[8]:
Name: java.util.zip.ZipException
Message: error in opening zip file
StackTrace: java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:235)
java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:165)
java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:179)
```

I tried all sort of URLs - raw, file etc. as specified in this other link, but no help.

[%AddJar for hellospark_2.10-1.0.jar giving Name: java.util.zip.ZipException Message: error in opening zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36873865/addjar-for-hellospark-2-10-1-0-jar-giving-name-java-util-zip-zipexception-mess)

Please advice.

Thanks
Raj

Answer (score 0):

Your URL points to an HTML page with a download button. You must use a URL that points to the actual JAR file instead. I got it by right-clicking on the download button and selecting "Copy Link Address". The URL has `/raw/` instead of `/blob/` in the path:

```
%AddJar https://github.com/ibm-cds-labs/spark.samples/raw/master/dist/helloSpark-assembly-2.1.jar -f
```

That line "worked" for me, in the sense that I got a totally different error messages on the first try: Assertion failed. After restarting the kernel and re-executing the `%AddJar`, the error was gone. Maybe my service didn't have the download directory yet when I executed the line for the first time.